# json_decode after JSON stringify not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an javascript array which is json encoded and posted to PHP. 
when I check a value in the array before posting 
ie `console.log(selection[878][2824])` I'm getting a value as its result. and then the variable is json encoded using `JSON.stringify`  and posted to server. But when I `json_decode` the value in php and printed the same, I'm getting null array

**js script**

```
    console.log(selection);
    $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'example.php',
                data: 'selection='+JSON.stringify(selection),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
```

**php script**

```
$selectionData = json_decode($_POST['selection']);
print_r($selectionData[878][2824]);
```

So what is happening while encoding the data here. How is it lost ?

Comment: can you provide the json string in $_POST['selection']

Comment: It looks like you missed a comma "," after data: 'selection='+JSON.stringify(selection)...

Comment: @amdixon I have some other data also with is like the user id.

Comment: @MuhammadAli sorry that was a mistake when I copy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems data is not correctly formatted i think  you must format the string in

```
"selection :"  +JSON.stringify(selection);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

js

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {selection : JSON.stringify(selection)}
        })
```

php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$selection = json_decode($data['selection'],true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to stringify your content when you are using POST, just set the right headers.

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: selection,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
```

or if you need it with an identifier:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {"selection": selection },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
```

and in PHP (if you are using the additional identifier):

```
$selectionData = $_POST['selection'];
```